# How to search button

Tags: c#

Hello i have problem with search button i would like to find User by his name or email and so.

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
string search= textBox7.Text;
List<string> Content = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
foreach (string Text in Content)
{
    string[] vektor = Text.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string Name = vektor[0];
    string Street= vektor[1];
    string Telefon = vektor[2];
    string Email = vektor[3];

    if (vektor[0].ToLower() == (search.ToLower()))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add($"{Name},{Street},{Telefon},{Email}");
    }
    else if (Street.ToLower() == search.ToLower())
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add($"{Name},{Street},,{Telefon},{Email}");
    }
}
textBox7.Clear();
```

Comment: You did not ask a question. What problem do you have with the code?

Comment: You already wrote the code for finding a user by name or address. Why were you able to write code just like that without problems, but then suddenly somehow not being able anymore to write similar code for finding a user by email?

Comment: but i cant find user by telefon and email
Is it possible to write it more complex istead of wrintg many if ?

Answer (score 1):

First off: a good instinct, that "there must be something better than writing a bunch of if's".

You can combine several checks inside that `if`:

```
if (string.Equals(Name,    search, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
 || string.Equals(Street,  search, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
 || string.Equals(Telefon, search, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
 || string.Equals(Email,   search, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    listBox1.Items.Add($"{Name},{Street},{Telefon},{Email}");
}
```

- That I wrote this condition over several lines is just for readability, the compiler doesn't care
- I used `string.Equals`, as that saves creating two string copies (as `.ToLower()` would do)
- The `||` is the [boolean logical OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-) operator. Unlike English where "or" usually is used in "either one *or* the other", here it means "at least one of the two must be true"
- The `||` (unlike `|` which also exists) uses "short-circuiting" - if the first condition is true, then there is no need to check the second one as the combined result will be `true` anyway. Very handy for `if (myObject == null || myObject.Value == 0) ...`
- There is also `&&` ("AND") for when *both* parts must be true.